# Reg: Asp.net site not able to login

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api

I have ASP.net site login with username and password having OTP set on some number, can i get that number so that able to login to site.

thanks,

Comment: want to know for verification code which email and mobile number details, as the setup done by developer but now no access in the organization, site is myasp.net

Comment: Could it be possible to share the code for better investigation? At this moment its not clear where might be the problem. Better clarity is required.

Comment: when loginng to asp.net site, with username and password able to login but password is expired and OTP is getting send to Email id, we don't have that email id, tried with control panel setting to get the email id, but there also same password expired.

Comment: Without required code and details how come community contributor would assist on this.